# Windows authentication not working for a 2.0 asp.net web app deployed in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-2.0

I have deployed a asp.net 2.0 framework web application on IIS 7.0.

I have enabled the windows authentication and disabled all other authentications. The managed pipelined mode is classic. Pass through authentication is checked as well.

The web app is required to display the "Welcome username".
However, it is not taking the username from the windows login and displaying "Welcome System".

The app pool identity is set to Local System. If I change the app pool identity to Network service, it shows "Welcome Network Service".

I changed the applicationhost file as well to enable the windows authentication in it but that didn't help too.
I have moved NLTM over Negotiate in providers as well.

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
    string domainUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Replace("\\", "/");
        string UserId = domainUser.Substring(domainUser.IndexOf("/") + 1);
        Session.Add("UserId", UserId);
        lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome " + Session["UserId"].ToString()+"!";
}

Comment: The code works fine and picks windows username when I test using development server.After deployment on IIS,it is giving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Setting Impersonate=true worked.